# Electron open & keep open cmd.exe

Tags: windows, electron

I'm building a little tool that should among other thing allow me to start a Tomcat server.

Pretty easy, I just want a button to launch `startup.bat` and another to call `shutdown.bat`.

It works quite well (server start and stop) but completely in ninja mode, I can't manage to get the Tomcat console with the logs.
From a classic command line if I call `startup.bat`, a Window is opened with logs inside.
I tried `exec`, `execFile`, `spawn`. I tried calling directly the `bat`, the `cmd.exe`, even tried `start`. But I can't get the Window.

I know I can get streams, but I would like not to bother with that.

Also I'm just using the tool on Windows, no need to think about other platform for the moment.

```
const ipc = require('electron').ipcMain;
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;

ipc.on('start-local-tomcat', function (event) {
    execFile('cmd.exe', ['D:\\DEV\\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\\bin\\startup.bat'],
    {env: {'CATALINA_HOME': 'D:\\DEV\\apache-tomcat-8.0.12'}},
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    })
});

ipc.on('stop-local-tomcat', function (event) {
    execFile('cmd.exe',['D:\\DEV\\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\\bin\\shutdown.bat'],
    {env: {'CATALINA_HOME': 'D:\\DEV\\apache-tomcat-8.0.12'}},
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just didn't read the doc enough, there is a parameter called `detached` that will do exactly what I want:

```
var child = spawn(
     'D:\\DEV\\apache-tomcat-8.0.12\\bin\\startup.bat',
     {
         env: {'CATALINA_HOME': 'D:\\DEV\\apache-tomcat-8.0.12'},
        detached: true 
     }
);
```